# error when creating a new environment, UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to create a new environment from yml file and it is not successful. Not sure what is the problem? Can anyone give me a hand? Thanks

```
(base) U:\Data>conda env create -f dash_env.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): failed

(base) U:\Data>conda env create -f dash_env.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
  channel name: plotly
  channel url: http://anaconda-teamedition.cnrl.com/api/repo/plotly
  error code: 404

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.
```

The data in my yml file starts with these:

```
name: dash
channels:
  - plotly
  - bashtage
  - conda-forge
  - anaconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _tflow_select=2.3.0=mkl
  - absl-py=0.15.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - aiohttp=3.8.1=py38h2bbff1b_0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Team *(Enterprise)* edition of Anaconda - this means that you are using a restricted *or on premises* server which will have channels other than the public ones. In this case it looks like the plotly channel is not included in your permitted or hosted list.

You can do one of:

1. Search the available channels for one that includes a version of plotly
2. Contact your system administrators to request the channel be made available.

Comment: Thanks Steve, yes I probably use Team edition of Anaconda in our company. how to search available channels? Where to find them? It is not just plotly, also anaconda, conda-forge channels etc. Thanks

Comment: From the docs one possibility is `anaconda-enterprise-cli channels list` if you have access to that tool.

Comment: Alternatively checking your `.condarc` file should get you the URL of the configured server(s) - browse to there and click on `channels` if you can.

Comment: Yes Steve, I am trying find .condarc file and I cannot find it.

Comment: I *_think_* it is likely to be in your home directory _(but probably invisible)_ - if it isn't there you can try `conda config --list channels`